How to nest queries with two variable in Xquery
I have two XML datasets, and I save them into two variables in SQL
XML data of @inforsv:
<SinhVien MSSV="1" TenSV="Sang" MaKhoaHoc="1" />
<SinhVien MSSV="2" TenSV="Duy" MaKhoaHoc="2" />
<SinhVien MSSV="3" TenSV="Sa" MaKhoaHoc="3" />

XML data of @inforKhoa:
<KhoaHoc MaKhoaHoc="1" TenKhoaHoc="Mang May Tinh Truyen Thong" />
<KhoaHoc MaKhoaHoc="2" TenKhoaHoc="Khoa Hoc May Tinh" />
<KhoaHoc MaKhoaHoc="3" TenKhoaHoc="Ky Thuat May Tinh" />

Here is my code
DECLARE @inforKhoa XML;

SET @inforKhoa = (SELECT * 
                  FROM KhoaHoc
                  FOR XML AUTO);

--PRINT CAST(@inforKhoa AS NVARCHAR(MAX));

DECLARE @inforsv XML;
SET @inforsv = (SELECT * 
                FROM SinhVien
                FOR XML AUTO);

I want to combine SinhVien and KhoaHoc by loop through two variable and I save in @merge
DECLARE @merge XML;

SET @merge = @inforsv.query(
        'for $i in //SinhVien
         let $a := @inforkhoa.query("//KhoaHoc")
            for $j in $a
            where $j[@MaKhoaHoc] = $i[@MaKhoaHoc]
         return <INFOR>{ $i, $j}</INFOR>
        ')

PRINT CAST(@merge AS nvarchar(MAX))

However, I get an error:

XQuery [query()]: Syntax error near '('


So you're expected results are what exactly?

Why are you getting the result sets as XML individually and then trying to join the XML? Rather than join the tables in SQL and get that join result as XML?

If you must go that route then maybe this? https://dbfiddle.uk/2yfqiZoX - seems very inefficient doing a nested loops join in XML rather than getting the database to do it on the source though!

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Overall, SQL Server doesn't allow to pass a variable of XML data type to XQuery methods. It is a current limitation.

Can you join the tables before converting it to XML?

thank you very much everyone, i try to query by join table and i convert successfully to XML.
Once again, I sincerely thank you for your comments
